# Do we use "poke" or "thrust" with knives and swords?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

When writing about a battle between a prince with a sword and a dragon, do we use "**poke**" or "**thrust**"?

For example, "**the prince poked the dragon in the wing with his sword**" or "**the prince thrust the dragon in the wing with his sword**" or "**the prince thrust at the dragon's wing with his sword**"

Comment: You do not thrust the dragon. You thrust the sword.

Comment: You could technically poke a dragon with a sword, but not in the context of a battle.  Poke isn't a 'fighting' verb. You'd poke it to see if if was dead (or asleep), which might not end very well for you!

Answer (score 1):

"Thrust" is a verb often associated with both sword and knife combat"poke" not so much. Another such word is "stab" (though generally much more with knives than swords).

However, I would usually expect an attack against a dragon's wing to be some kind of slash (that is an arcing movement). I suppose if your hero is on top of the dragon he might stab down then pull rather than slash from the start.

Comment: To use _poke_ would  suggest that he was a very inexpert fighter, who used a sword as though he were poking the fire. '_Lunged_ at the dragon' would be another possibility.

Comment: @KateBunting, The sentence "**he poked the dragon in the wing with a sword**" implies the dragon actually got injured. However, "**he thrust at the dragon with a sword**" does not imply the dragon was injured.

I am not sure if we can say "**he thrust the dragon in the wing with a sword**"?

Comment: If we already know the prince is armed with a sword, it's not necessary to specify that he used it to wound the dragon. You could say "He made a thrust and pierced the dragon's wing", "He lunged at the dragon and caught it in the wing" or various other permutations.

Comment: No, @Tom.  The direct object of "to thrust" is the implement, not the target.  If the hero thrust the dragon, then we're dealing with either an immensely strong hero or a much smaller and lighter dragon than I usually imagine.  Verbs that can have a target as a direct object include *poke, prod, pierce, stab, strike* and the like.  Verbs that have an implement as a direct object include *thrust, wave, swing, aim, point* and so on.  You might want to consider your prepositional options: not just *thrust at* but *thrust into* and *thrust through.*